# How to create math ( Geometry , Analytic Geometry ) worksheets

Tags: education, math-software

I apologize if this is not the site for such questions.

But I need a software that can create math worksheets in geometry and also adding axes with viewing important points in the plane, basically I want to create math problems for high school students (not something fancy) but something to do the job.

I am aware of GeoGebra but its not like the worksheets I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe see if this meets your criteria: http://www.dynamicgeometry.com/index.html

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Ahmad: You might also consider http://www.mathcomposer.com/, https://www.kutasoftware.com/freeige.html

Comment: Consider LaTeX :)

Comment: Thank you all, it helped.